# PPA and direct installs won't work...bad file

Tags: software-installation, fsck

16.04LTS...new install on a replacement HDD...anything but a deb file will not install. Shows a file in /etc/apt with an "invalid file type" and dumps the install. Deb files work OK. I'm thinking I should boot USB and FSCK the directory. Could use some input.[image]

Comment: What PPA? What deb? Pleaase edit you question and describe exactly what you're trying to do, what are the expected results and what's happening instead.

Comment: ALL debs. ALL ppas. I'm simply trying to install (1) Bitcoin Core, and (2) Seamonkey. I had both installed and working on the old drive. In each case the install will proceed, then fail at the same place because of a file named /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist being a bad file type. I could install LibreOffice, Teamviewer, and a number of others using deb files with no issues, and a couple from the Ubuntu center.  The ppa install for Bitcoin also fails for the same reason.  Wassup?

Comment: I added the screenshot...this was during the apt-get update, but the same error.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (≥100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: There are some warnings and notices in the output of `apt-get update` but nothing serious that should prevent package installation by Apt altogether. Could you please include the output of an example of a package installation via `apt-get install -f <PACKAGE>` in your question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the error messages, in the `terminal`, type:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist ~/Documents
```

this will move the offending file to your Documents folder. The file was originally created during a "unattended-upgrades" `Software Update`. If needed in the future, it will be recreated as "20auto-upgrades", without user action.

Comment: YOWZA! Thank you! That was exactly what I needed to hear. This will likely solve the issue with Seamonkey and another app.  I had no clue, and couldn't find anything anywhere. I will also try to use a bit more elocution in my posts (re David Foerster). This is the first I've had to ask for help, and this seems to be the place to get it.

Comment: Why not just delete the offending file?

Comment: @KazWolfe posterity might want to see it...

Comment: Fair enough, but at least `chown` it over to the user so you don't have root things all over the home folder.